# How can i get my While-loop to exit/break, when i release the button?

Tags: c#, while-loop

whats the problem here ? why does the while loop need to finnish to get the keyup event even that i already released it..

I know its just the while, cuz if i use only textboxes, keyIsDown doesnt change value until i release the button.

```cs
void KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyIsDown = true;
    if (e.KeyCode.ToString() == "F6")
    {
        while(keyIsDown)
        {
            //do something
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (!keyIsDown)
                break;
            //do something
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (!keyIsDown)
                break;
            //do something
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (!keyIsDown)
                break;
            //do something
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (!keyIsDown)
                break;
            break;
        }           
    }
    e.Handled = false;
}

void KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    keyIsDown = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, while your `KeyDown` method runs in a loop, other methods cannot run. I.e., `KeyUp` will never run and you get stuck.

In a Windows Forms (winforms) application, an event will never be interrupted for another event. The second event hander (`KeyUp`) must wait untiel the first one terminates.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, as you code doesn't do anything besides waiting.

If you want to do some kind of animation, you could start a timer on key down (without any loop), then animate at every tick of the timer, and finally, stop the animation at key up.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Timer _timer = new Timer();
    private readonly string[] _messages =
        { "hello", "world", "", "folks", "we", "made", "it", "" };
    private int _index;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Interval = 500; // Milliseconds
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = _messages[_index];
        _index = (_index + 1) % _messages.Length;
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F6) {
            _timer.Start();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        label1.Text = "stopped";
        _index = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that the application is always waiting for events to happen. Then it processes the event and waits again. We say that a winforms application is event-driven.

Comment: oh tanks man. i think a timer will do it.
but, lets say i have i want to write 
"hello" first 50ms.
then, world, second 99ms..
and for every 99ms, its not the same text, its different text every tick..

Comment: Then you must store the current state, so that you can resume at the next timer tick. I changed the example. The state is represented by `_index`. This code loops the messages while F6 is pressed.

Comment: thanks! i think i get it.. will look into this tomorrow.. :D